# Increasing cluster performance

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm clustering a data set with categorical data using kmodes and it's starting to take too long. I'm considering two approaches:
1) reduce the number of iterations 2) randomly pick a smaller subset of the data, get the centroids, and then assign the rest of the data a cluster based on the closest centroid.

I'm wondering what the trade off would be between these two approaches, or if there are other approaches that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: How good is your implementation? If it uses a lot of R code, consider rewriting it in C or Fortran for performance. Naive R code can be easily 10x slower than native code. Using more clever data structures (which are hard to do in R efficiently) may get you another factor of 10x-100x.